# Lower div border is visible although upper div has other border

Tags: html, css

I have a few div elements on the page, each has its own border.
The problem is that the lower div border ("#a") is visible although other elements ("#b", "c#") are on top of it.

see the following JS fiddle for example and code: http://jsfiddle.net/4jntf/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b" class="quarter"></div>
    <div id="c" class="quarter"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
}

#a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border-top-right-radius: 55px;
    border-width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 104px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}

#b {
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border-width: 4px 2px 4px 4px;
    float: left;
}

#c {
    border-width: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 55px;

    float: right;
}
.quarter {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

the desired effect I want to get is to always see the middle line, click the button to see desired effect.

the only way I have been able to get the desired effect is by giving div "#a" CSS z-index of -1, but this causes all other elements in page to be on top of it and practically invisible.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `#a` isn't visible. The element on top of it (`#b` and `#c`) just have the same background as `#a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border-top-right-radius: 55px;
    border-width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 104px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -112px;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/H2jey/

Comment: thanks, this is not exactly what I wanted, but it allowed me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the #a background to transparent?

http://jsfiddle.net/4jntf/1/

```
#a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border-top-right-radius: 55px;
    border-width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 104px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would you like something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4jntf/2/)?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b" class="quarter"></div>
    <div id="c" class="quarter"></div>
    <div id="d" class="line"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="change">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").click(function () {
        if ($("#a").is(":visible")) {
                $("#a").hide();
            $("#d").css('z-index', -1);
            } else {
                $("#a").show();
                $("#d").css('z-index', 1);
            }        
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
}
#a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border-top-right-radius: 55px;
    border-width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 104px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
.line{
    width: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    left: 54px;
    z-index: 5;
    background: red;
}
#b {
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border-width: 4px 2px 4px 4px;
    float: left;
}
#c {
    border-width: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 55px;

    float: right;
}
.quarter {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}
```